# Using nested queries in left join

Tags: oracle, left-join

I have two tables emp_master and transfer. for each employee_id 
in emp_master there can be multiple entries in transfer table. I want to get the latest
record from the transfer table based on date_of_tansfer and display it with data from 
     emp_master. I have written a query like this which is not working. I am getting a error 
    "EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID: invalid identifier". I can get the details for single employee if i   hardcode
     it with that employee_id.. but how can i modify it to get data for all the employees..

```
select distinct emp.employee_id,trnsf.OU
from emp_master emp 
left join (select * from (select * from transfer where employee_id = emp.employee_id 
and date_of_transfer <= SYSDATE order by date_of_transfer desc) where rownum = 1) trnsfr
on trnsfr.EMPLOYEE_ID = emp.employee_id


CREATE TABLE "EMP_MASTER" 
   ( "EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
     "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
     "MIDDLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
     "SURNAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
   ) 

 CREATE TABLE "TRANSFER" 
   (    "EMPLOYEE_SR_NO" NUMBER, 
        "EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
        "DATE_OF_TRANSFER" DATE, 
        "OU" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error is the nesting level of your derived tables (sub-queries). A sub-query can "see" only the columns/tables from the immediate "parent" query (which in your case is the outer select that limits the result to one row).

The following should do what you want:

```
select distinct emp.employee_id, trnsfr.ou
from emp_master emp 
left join (
      select transfer.employee_id,
             transfer.ou,
             row_number() over (order by date_of_transfer desc) as rn
      from transfer 
      where date_of_transfer <= SYSDATE 
    ) trnsfr
    on trnsfr.employee_id = emp.employee_id and trnsfr.rn = 1;
```

If `date_of_transfer` is really a "DATE" (i.e. no time involved) than you might consider using `date_of_transfer <= trunc(SYSDATE)` instead in order to "remove" the time from the SYSDATE result.

Comment: I tried it....bu i am getting an error FROM keyword not found
select *,row_number() over (order by date_of_transfer desc) as rn from hris_transfer_dtl 
where employee_id = emp.employee_id and date_of_transfer <= SYSDATE ...this query itself is giving that error...

Comment: above error is because of *..i added alias.* and i got it working....but for the whole query i am getting the same error emp.Employee_id invalid identifier..

Comment: @Jasim: I fixed the error. There was a prefix missing for the * and the `where employee_id = emp.employee_id` is not necessary because that is part of the join condition anyway.

Comment: i tried...query is not throwing any error now...but the data im getting is not correct for most of the record value for column OU is null..only for one row it is coming proper.....

Comment: @Jasim: well that is to be expected when using an outer join. Are you sure you have at least one row for each employee_id in `emp_master`

Comment: @horse ..no that is not the case.... there can be or cannot be rows in transfer table...if it is not there i want to get it as null

Comment: @Jasim: you will get a NULL if there is no matching row in the transfer table. That's the whole point of a LEFT JOIN

Comment: @horse yes...i know..but im getting the OU value for only one record....rest all the value is null evnethough im having data in database...

Comment: @Jasim: you should create a new question **including** sample data that shows your problem. Your original question (the syntax problem) has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query with inner join and a sub-query:

```
SELECT * FROM EMP_MASTER T1 
INNER JOIN TRANSFER T2 ON T1.employee_id =T2.employee_id 
WHERE T2.DATE_OF_TRANSFER=(SELECT MAX(T3.DATE_OF_TRANSFER) FROM TRANSFER T3 WHERE T3.employee_id =T2.employee_id );
```

Comment: this query is nopt working in case if there is no record in transfer table...i want to populate null incase there is no data...

Comment: Please try this: SELECT * FROM EMP_MASTER T1 LEFT  JOIN TRANSFER T2 ON T1.employee_id=T2.employee_id
WHERE NVL(T2.DATE_OF_TRANSFER,SYSDATE) =NVL((SELECT MAX(T3.DATE_OF_TRANSFER) FROM TRANSFER T3 WHERE T3.employee_id=T2.employee_id),SYSDATE);